# TermsAggregation on Array

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-aggregation

have a problem with an index field that stores a list of strings in the way of

["abc_def_fgh", "abc_def_fgh" ,"123_345_456"]

Im trying to use TermsAggregation to get

"abc_def_fgh" (2)
"123_345_456" (1)

But cant get it working, as it results the count for each of the terms (abc (2), def(2) , etc)

Any idea?

Many thanks

Comment: maybe share some code so we can understand the context. It depends on the analyzer and tokenizer that you've used. maybe elasticsearch strips the unserscore and separates the phrase into different words

Comment: Hi MaxG, thanks for answer. I tried changing the underscore for other characters (even strange characters) and it does the same. About code nothing more than adding TermsAggregation object with field name to aggregations (im using nest client)

Im new to elastic so im a bit lost, but will take a look to analyzer and tokenizers. Imported index with a tool and put standard analyzer

Thanks

Comment: what is the mapping type of this field you try to create an aggregation for?

Comment: Hi, is a text field storing an array of strings

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
var result = await client.SearchAsync<Document>(s => s
    .Size(0)
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("tags", t => t.Field(f => f.Tags.Suffix("keyword")))));

foreach (var bucket in result.Aggregations.Terms("tags").Buckets)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine($"Tag {bucket.Key}, doc count: {bucket.DocCount}");
}

public class Document
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string[] Tags { get; set; } = { };
}
```

for these three documents in my index

```
new Document {Id = "1", Tags = new[]{"a","b"}
new Document {Id = "2", Tags = new[]{"a"}
new Document {Id = "3", Tags = new[]{"c"}
```

it will output

```
Tag a, doc count: 2
Tag b, doc count: 1
Tag c, doc count: 1
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a mapping issue.  You need to make sure that you are using `keyword` opposed to `text`.  You do not want the field to be analyzed when using aggregations.